# Doctrine migrations diff keeps creating wrong information

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create migrations with doctrine:migrations:diff.
the database is now allready in a well enough state, but when i try to at something (such as name shown below) it also keeps trying to change the foreign key.

But it keeps trying to change the FK key:

```
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE order_manager ADD name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE orders RENAME INDEX fk_e6ab879d9395c3f3 TO IDX_E52FFDEE9395C3F3');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE orders RENAME INDEX fk_e6ab879dcbe4c936 TO IDX_E52FFDEECBE4C936');
    }
```

Here is the entity class:

```
class Orders extends BaseEntity
{ 
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="orders", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", nullable=true)
 */
private $customer;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrderManager", inversedBy="orders", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_manager_id", nullable=true)
 */
private $orderManager;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getCustomer(): Customer
{
    return $this->customer;
}

public function setCustomer(Customer $customer)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
}

public function getOrderManager(): orderManager
{
    return $this->orderManager;
}

public function setOrderManager(orderManager $orderManager)
{
    $this->orderManager = $orderManager;
}
}
```

When trying to do doctrine:migrations:migrate I get this error

An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE orders RENAME INDEX fk_e6ab879d9395c3f3 TO IDX_E52FFDEE9395C3F3':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX fk_e6ab879d9395c3f3 TO IDX_E52FFDEE9395C3F3' at line 1

Comment: What happen when you try `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` ? Do you have the same output ?

Comment: Jup:

 The following SQL statements will be executed:

     ALTER TABLE orders RENAME INDEX fk_e6ab879d9395c3f3 TO IDX_E52FFDEE9395C3F3;
     ALTER TABLE orders RENAME INDEX fk_e6ab879dcbe4c936 TO IDX_E52FFDEECBE4C936;

Comment: That must be it, for some reason your schema is not up to date. There is no problem here I assume, you just gotta leave those un your migration I reckon

Comment: Well the problem is that  I get errrors when trying to migrate now :

check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX fk_e6ab879d9395c3f3 TO IDX_E52FFDEE9395C3F3' at line 1

Comment: I added the full error to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you added those indexes by hand. What you need to do is tell doctrine the `name` of your indexes using `@ORM\Index` annotation. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-index